# Bind Boolean Value to a combobox in Vaadin

Tags: combobox, vaadin

I have a POJO which has gender value of customers as  Boolean. I haveto  make a combobox in a form which is data source is Customer type.
How can I make the combobox have "Male" and "Female" choices which will be binded to Boolean values.

Thanks.
Form Code:

```
Form customerForm= new BeanValidationForm<Customer>(Customer.class);
```

Customer POJO:

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
public static final String QUERY_ALL = "Customer.queryAll";
public static final String QUERY_BY_ID = "Customer.queryById";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
private String name;
@Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
private String surname;
@Column(nullable = false)
private Boolean gender;

//getters and setters....
}
```

Comment: Have a look at: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.selecting.html Your requirement is described there. You have to add your items (True, false) and then add a itemDescription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
    comboBox.addItem(true);
    comboBox.setItemCaption(true, "Male");
    comboBox.addItem(false);
    comboBox.setItemCaption(false, "Feemale");
```

But I would recommend using an enum here and save it as     @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
Imagine if someone new enters your team, he'll have to learn what these 1 and 0 mean (in DB).